# How to rid of "seams" from texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

When I paint my model made from Blender in Substance Painter, always uv seams is visible and interrupt textures like this:

[image]

Reason of asking here because I don't sure this caused from Blender or Substance Painter(I also asked this in SP forum).

Anyway I think this caused from my UV map, so I tried to add some padding between islands or triangulate all quads but none of them worked.

Here's the UV map of my model:

[image]

Note that all faces are smooth shaded.

This issue always happens to me and I really want to fix this in this time. As you can see in the UV map, I just added seams and unwrap all together.

If this caused from my UV map, how should I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the image options in the UV Editor to better unwrap your mesh first. Try the Color Grid to see how the image flows on your mesh object first before trying to go to Substance Painter to make the texture paint, as Substance won't correct a bad UV Unwrap. Look into unwrapping each part separately using 'Follow Active Quads' to get a better alignment and flow on the mesh.